# Calling C# Method Within Powershell Core

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm attempting to call a C# dll within Powershell Core.
The C# dll has been created using [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).
Here is the C# code I'm trying to call.

```
public partial class Fiery
{
    private Fiery(){}

    /// <summary>
    /// Establishes authorized user access to the Fiery API features
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printer"></param>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin.Login Login(Printer printer, string username, string password)
    {
        // Apply Certificate.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", IsCertificateValidationApplied.Value ? "Certificate Applied" : "Certificate Was Unable To Be Applied");
        EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin.Login loginResponse = SendLoginRequest(printer, username, password).Result;

        return loginResponse;
    }
}
```

And here is the powershell script.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('\\foo\bar\netstandard2.0\EFI-Fiery-API.dll')
[EFI.Fiery]::AccessKey = "foo"

$printer = New-Object EFI.Fiery+Printer -ArgumentList "0.0.0.0";
$username = "admin";
$password = [System.String]::Empty;

$loginResult = New-Object EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin+Login -ArgumentList $printer,$username,$password;

if ($loginResult.IsSuccess){
    #do something.
}
```

This is the error

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Login" and the argument count: "3".
>   + ... ginResult = New-Object EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin+Login -ArgumentList $ ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

So I tried,

```
if ([EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin+Login]::new($printer,$username,$password)){
    #do something.
}
```

And I received

> Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "3".
>   + if ([EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin+Login]::new($printer,$username,$passwor ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

I finally tried

```
if ([EFI_Fiery_API.FieryLogin+Login]::new([EFI.Fiery+Printer]$printer,[System.String]$username, 
[System.String]$password)){
    #do something.
}
```

The error is the same as above.
Something that I thought was a little odd was the fact that I can invoke methods that have a single parameter.

```
if ([EFI.Fiery]::Logout($printer)){
    #works.
}
```

Here is how the class is being classed in a C# application.

```
        // AccessKey.
        EFI.Fiery.AccessKey = "foo";

        // The Printer.
        EFI.Fiery.Printer printer = new EFI.Fiery.Printer("0.0.0.0");

        // Login To The Printer.
        var loginResults = EFI.Fiery.Login(printer, "admin", null);

        // Login To The Printer.
        if (loginResults.IsSuccess)
        {
```

Here Is The Error From The Exception.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__0()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.<SendLoginRequest>d__41.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.Login(Printer printer, String username, String password)\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object , Object )\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\r\nFile name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__0()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at EFI.Fiery.d__41.MoveNext()\r\n\r\nWRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.\r\nTo enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.\r\nNote: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.\r\nTo turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].\r\n<---\r\n

This tells me that I am missing Json package, I added it however, it didnt help, I will check that I am using the correct version.

Ok Turns out I didnt have the assembly imported correctly,
I ened up using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(path to .net standard json dll)`

and it worked, Thanks @mklement0 for pointing out`$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` to get the innter exception in the hierarchy.

Comment: It looks like `Login` is a _static method_, yet you're trying to call it as a _constructor_.

Comment: arrggh yes, you're correct, I even tried `$results = [EFI.Fiery]::Login("0.0.0.0", $username,$password);` I created another login method with a string type for printer and still receive the `Exception calling "Login" with "3" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."` error.

Comment: Yes, `[EFI.Fiery]::Login(...)` is how you call static method `Login` on type `EFI.Fiery`.  It sounds like you're now able to call the method, but it throws an exception.

Comment: As the code works in a console app, the only other dependency I can see that the class is using is Newtonsoft Json, maybe I need to add that to the PS Script as well

Comment: Unfortunately no change.

Comment: So where does the exception come from? Does it have an inner exception that tells you more? (`$Error[0].Exception.InnerException`)

Comment: Updating The Question.

Comment: @AndrewE Have you read this paper? http://executeautomation.com/blog/calling-c-code-in-powershell-and-vice-versa/

Comment: not at this stage, but Ill be sure to take a look :) Thanks for the link,.